Selenium with Chrome for testing Strange Behavior
Selenium and Chrome For Testing, how to disable the new browser.driver download?
I have Chrome For Testing and chromedriver installed in a custom location, and everything works, but it downloads the newer version(and does nothing with them everytime I run the script.)
I can watch in task manager as it maxes out my internet for a while downloading.
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_path = r"testing\chrome-win64\chrome.exe"
options.binary_location = chrome_path
#options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
#options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
#options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("disable-extensions");
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": "my\\directory",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "credentials_enable_service": False,
  "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
})

Service('testing/driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

Here is the log-
Selenium Manager set by env SE_MANAGER_PATH to: C:\******\Scripts\selenium-manager.exe
Selenium Manager binary found at: C:\*******\Scripts\selenium-manager.exe
Executing process: C:******\Scripts\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --browser-path testing\chrome-win64\chrome.exe --debug --language-binding python --output json
chromedriver not found in PATH
Running command: wmic datafile where name='C:******\\testing\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe' get Version /value
Output: ""
Running command: REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon /v version
Output: ""
chrome not found in the system
Required browser: chrome 126.0.6478.182
chrome 126.0.6478.182 already exists
chrome 126.0.6478.182 is available at C:\******\.cache\selenium\chrome\win64\126.0.6478.182\chrome.exe
Required driver: chromedriver 126.0.6478.182
chromedriver 126.0.6478.182 already in the cache
Driver path: C:******\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\126.0.6478.182\chromedriver.exe


I do have the chrome 126.0.6478.183 (just updated) as my normal browser, the CFT is in a seperate location.
Name: selenium
Version: 4.22.0
CFT Version 126.0.6478.182

from this article and this article CFT version 113 and onwards has an integrated feature to auto-download the ChromeDriver to make testing a bit easier
now from your code snippet, I see that there is a bug where you are declaring service = Service() at the first line of your code then at the last line you have this Service('testing/driver/chromedriver.exe') which is breaking the whole point of using service maybe that's why the ChromeDriver is being auto-downloaded
try to remove your first line of code and fix the last like this 'service = Service("testing/driver/chromedriver.exe")' and see if this will stop the auto-downloading if it didn't stop, try to add this chrome-driver folder testing/driver/ to your system path for windows follow this answer and for Linux follow this answer
now if none of them worked for you, I couldn't find any solution on stopping the auto-download so, you can either use normal Chrome or ignore it
